# Using mixins i want to add @include two times in a same class

Tags: sass

I'm using flexbox. I want to add Mixin @include for flex property Ex: `flex-basis`, `flex` etc with vendor prefixes. Adding `gutter` is not working. I want this code in pure SASS.

```css
$default-grid-gutter: 2%;

.grid {
 @include grid($gutter: $default-grid-gutter);

    > .grid__col-3 {
        @include grid-col($col: 3, $gutter: $default-grid-gutter);
    }
    > .grid__col-9 {
        @include grid-col($col: 9, $gutter: $default-grid-gutter);
    }
}

.grid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  
}

.grid > .grid__col-3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 23%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 23%;
  flex: 0 0 23%;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid > .grid__col-9 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 73%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 73%;
  flex: 0 0 73%;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid__col-3">
    3
</div>
<div class="grid__col-9">
    9
</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see $value defined, but not $values. Is it defined elsewhere? If you're still facing this issue, have you tried changing that?

Comment: yeah, i.e $value only. but it should be anything it just a variable name. my question is how I have to include this two properties flexbox and flex in the same class. I don't know more about sass just I have started.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried the same code, but changed `$values` to `$value` and it compiles.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/roveliv/edit?html,css,output

Comment: HTML:   <div class="grid">
<div class="grid__col-3">
    3
</div>
<div class="grid__col-9">
    9
</div>
</div>

Comment: Is this related to a different issue you're facing? Can you please accept the answer if it resolved your question?

Comment: @bazzells I edited my question once check. In my code, I didn't add vendor prefixes I have to add later feel free to tell any mistake in the code. so, if you know the correct way to write this logic try once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only issue is that you're referencing a variable `$values` that isn't defined. Changing your parameter that's defined in your mixin from `$value` to `$values` will resolve it.